# Titanium Alloy - TabGroup - more menu controller

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I have a Titanium Alloy mobile project on TA 3.2.2 for iOS with the following scenario.

**tabs.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <TabGroup id="tbMenu" allowUserCustomization="false">
        <Require src="tab1" />
        <Require src="tab2" />   
        ...
        <Require src="tab99" />
    </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

**tab10.xml**

```
<Alloy>
    <Tab id="tab10">
        <Window id="win10" navBarHidden="true" tabBarHidden="true" onFocus="doTask">
            <ActivityIndicator id="acView" message="Loading..." />
        </Window>
    </Tab>
</Alloy>
```

Under iOS, all tabs after the 4th are put in a "more" view controller. When tab10.xml is opened it hides both the tabbar (TabGroup) and the navigation bar. This view starts a task that does something and when the task finishes the tab10.xml needs to close and the app should return to the "more" controller/view screen - the one with the list of all views after tab4.xml.

Now, the problem is that whatever method, object, action or global variable i've used it doesn't work - meaning when the task finishes, the windows stays open and if let's say i do this :

```
setActiveTab(X);
```

for whatever X value, next time i press the MORE menu it opens tab10.xml.

So, the question is - when the task finishes in tab10.xml how can i pop/close tab10.xml from the "more" view controller (by "more" view controller i mean what's referenced in Titanium docs as "More tab" and in iOS it's called "moreNavigationController")?

Any help or advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: That's really good question. I started playing around with multiple tabs and haven't come up with good resolution for it. The only hint I can give you right now is instead of creating tab with `tabBarHidden: true` try opening up window with `modal: true`, which will cover whole screen.

Comment: Thanks @daniula, but in this scenario i'm not sure how to open tab10 as modal. I've tried with the xml attributes modal="true" on the <Window> in tab10.xml, but it still treats it as a separate window in the navigation group. I'm not sure how to override the TabGroup click on tab and open window from the code AND ignore what's setup in the xml.

Comment: You open window which is in tab as regular window and inside it you create separate window outside of TabGroup with `modal: true`.